# Not able to render data from an API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue to render questions from an API, I created the state and used `useEffect` to call the API, but when I want to render it, it destroys all my css to render a blank page, I've tried to move the component to the `App`, but the problem remains.

Here is my App:

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import FirstPage from './components/firstPage'
import Quiz_page from './components/quiz'

function App() {
  const [start, setStart]= React.useState(true)
  const [game, setGame]= React.useState(false)

  function startGame(){
    setGame(true)
    setStart(false)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <bloc className='bloc'></bloc>
      <bloc className='bloc2'></bloc>
      {start && <FirstPage startGame={startGame}/>}
      {game && <Quiz_page/>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here is the concerned component :

```
import React from 'react';


function Quiz(props){

    const [quizData, setQuizData] = React.useState({});

    React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setQuizData(data))
    console.log(data)
    }, []);

    const displayQuestions = quizData.map((element)=>{<Questions key ={element.question}question={element.question}/>})

    

    return(
        
        <div className='questions'>
            {displayQuestions}
        </div>
        
    )
}


export default Quiz
```

Here are the console errors:

```
react-dom.development.js:12056 Uncaught TypeError: quizData.map is not a function
    at Quiz (quiz.jsx:15:39)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:20)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26096:20)
Quiz @ quiz.jsx:15
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26096
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:25651
```

Just to be precise, the blocs on the App are here to make pure CSS, and they are disappearing too when the const `displayQuestions` is created and not even rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `map` that's stored in `displayQuestions` is not returning a value for each iteration. You should either have a `return` before `<Questions...` or use parentheses, like so:

```js
const displayQuestions = quizData.map((element) => (
  <Questions key={element.question} question={element.question} />
));
```

Also, change your state to this as you want an array to map over:

```js
const [quizData, setQuizData] = React.useState([]);
```

Finally, our API is returning an object with the `results` key holding that actual array you want, so you should have:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetch(
    "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple"
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => setQuizData(data.results));
}, []);
```